# Existence of subgroup of order six in $A_4$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, permutations

> Show that  the  alternating  group  $A_4$  of all even permutations of $S_4$ does not contain a  subgroup of order $6$.

For me am thinking to write all elements of $A_4$ and trying to find every cyclic subgroup generated by each element of $A_4$, then I have to check whether there exist such a subgroup or not! This is a long procedure for me, I ask if there is a short way to do this.

Comment: If the subgroup has order $6$, then what can you say about the order of the quotient group? What can you conclude after that?

Comment: The quotient group has order 2

Comment: [Here](http://www.artofproblemsolving.com/Forum/viewtopic.php?f=61&t=447674) is the ML link.

Comment: Three proofs of this fact are given in Keith Conrad's notes [here.](http://www.math.uconn.edu/~kconrad/blurbs/grouptheory/A4noindex2.pdf). Highly recommended!

Comment: @azimut
This was asked two years later...

Comment: @АрсенийКряжевiswithUkraine but https://math.stackexchange.com/q/582658/61691 has the more comprehensive answers. In such a unbalanced case, it is common use to close the older one.

Answer (score 15):

Assume $H \le A_4$ is a subgroup of order 6. Then $H$ contains a unique subgroup $C$ of order 3. So $C$ is characteristic in $H.$ And as $H$ is normal in $A_4,$ we obtain $C$ is normal in $A_4.$ On the other hand, if $(a b c)$ is a generator of $C,$ conjugating $(abc)$ by $(ab)(cd) \in A_4$ we obtain $(bad) \not\in C,$ from which we obtain not only a contradiction, but a potential pun - not too shabby.

Comment: i get u,thanks a lot

Comment: @JuniorII It would be nice of you to upvote and accept jspecter's answer since you found it helpful.

Answer (score 2):

There are only two groups of order 6: the cyclic group of order 6, and a group isomorphic to $S_3$. But the maximum order of permutations in $S_4$ is 4, which excludes a cyclic subgroup of order 6, and $S_3$ includes simple interchanges, which are not in $A_4$.

Answer (score 1):

There is a proof in the QUESTION [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1099915/a-sub-theorem-inside-prove-that-the-group-a-4-has-no-subgroup-of-order-6?noredirect=1#comment2242365_1099915).

Note that There are twelve elements in $A_4$ : $(1),\ (12)(34),\ (13)(24),\ (14)(23),\ (123),\ (132),\ (124),\ (142),\ (134),\ (143),\ (234),\ (243)$.