# Group which doesn't have subgroup of degree d||G|.

Tags: group-theory, proof-verification

Today my teacher gave me the task: found finite group, which doesn't have subgroup of degree $d$ where $d$| |G|.

I thought about some special groups and actually about$\mathbb{Z}_{8}$, if there exist subgroup  H with 2 elements , then this group contain $e$ and $a^{-1}$, but $a^{-1} = \overline{7-a} $ so there is 3 elements. Does it true that $\mathbb{Z}_{8}$ is good for this?

Comment: No, you need $d$ to not be a prime and you need the group to not be abelian, otherwise you cannot find an example.

Comment: The first counter example to Lagrange's theorem actually occurs in $A_4$. You may wish to check to see which divisor does not have a corresponding subgroup.

Comment: You won't find examples among the abelian groups.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [$A_4$ has no subgroup of order $6$?](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/582658/a-4-has-no-subgroup-of-order-6)

Comment: See also [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2047583/let-g-be-a-finite-abelian-group-show-that-g-has-a-subgroup-of-order-d-for-ever), which explains why your example can't work.

Comment: @Watson it is NOT a duplicate of that question, please remove your comment.